# Transitive relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I have just started using neo4j.

I was trying to use it to describe a company's Enterprise Architecture.

I'd like to show that, by removing the node "Middleware", Service_A goes from Client_A and Server_X, and the same for the other services.

Is there a way to do that? Is this the right approach?

Next is the code used to generate the graph.

[image]

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import logging
from neo4j.exceptions import ServiceUnavailable


class App:

    def __init__(self, uri, user, password):
        self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))

    def close(self):
        # Don't forget to close the driver connection when you are finished with it
        self.driver.close()

    def drop_everything(self):
        with self.driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
            # Write transactions allow the driver to handle retries and transient errors
            session.execute_write(self._drop_everything)
            print("Graph DB dropped")

    @staticmethod
    def _drop_everything(tx):
        query = (
            "MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE (n)"
        )
        try:
            tx.run(query)

        # Capture any errors along with the query and data for traceability
        except ServiceUnavailable as exception:
            logging.error("{query} raised an error: \n {exception}".format(query=query, exception=exception))
            raise

    def create_system(self, system_name):
        with self.driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
            # Write transactions allow the driver to handle retries and transient errors
            result = session.execute_write(self._create_system, system_name)
            print("Created system: {p1}".format(p1=result))

    @staticmethod
    def _create_system(tx, system_name):
        # To learn more about the Cypher syntax, see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/
        # The Reference Card is also a good resource for keywords https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/
        query = (
            "CREATE (n:system{name:$system_name}) "
            "RETURN (n)"
        )
        result = tx.run(query, system_name=system_name)
        try:
            return result.single()[0]["name"]
        # Capture any errors along with the query and data for traceability
        except ServiceUnavailable as exception:
            logging.error("{query} raised an error: \n {exception}".format(query=query, exception=exception))
            raise

    def create_flow(self, service_name_a, system1_name, system2_name):
        with self.driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
            # Write transactions allow the driver to handle retries and transient errors
            result = session.execute_write(self._create_flow, service_name_a, system1_name, system2_name)
            print("Created flow: {p1}".format(p1=result))

    @staticmethod
    def _create_flow(tx, service_name, system1_name, system2_name):
        query = (
            "MATCH (p1:system), (p2:system) "
            "WHERE p1.name = '" + system1_name + "' AND p2.name = '" + system2_name +"' "
            "CREATE (p1)-[r:" + service_name + " {type:'call'}]->(p2) "
            "RETURN ('" + service_name + "')"
        )

        # CREATE (p1)-[r:service {name:'" + service_name + "'}]->(p2)
        # CALL apoc.create.relationship(p1, '$service_name', NULL, p2) YIELD rel
        # CREATE (p1)-[:service {name:'$service_name'}]->(p2) "

        result = tx.run(query, service_name=service_name, system1_name=system1_name, system2_name=system2_name)
        try:
            return service_name
        # Capture any errors along with the query and data for traceability
        except ServiceUnavailable as exception:
            logging.error("{query} raised an error: \n {exception}".format(query=query, exception=exception))
            raise

    def find_system(self, system_name):
        with self.driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
            result = session.execute_read(self._find_system, system_name)
            for row in result:
                print("Found system: {row}".format(row=row))

    @staticmethod
    def find_system(tx, system_name):
        query = (
            "MATCH (p:system) "
            "WHERE p.name = $system_name "
            "RETURN p.name AS name"
        )
        result = tx.run(query, system_name=system_name)
        return [{ row["name"] } for row in result]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Aura queries use an encrypted connection using the "neo4j+s" URI scheme
    # https://console.neo4j.io/ - Login with google mario.stefanutti@gmail.com
    uri = "neo4j+s://8a9f54ab.databases.neo4j.io"
    user = "neo4j"
    password = "Xxx"
    app = App(uri, user, password)

    app.drop_everything()

    app.create_system("Client_A")
    app.create_system("Middleware")
    app.create_system("Server_X")
    app.create_system("Server_Y")
    app.create_system("Server_Z")

    app.create_flow("Service_A", "Client_A", "Middleware")
    app.create_flow("Service_B", "Client_A", "Middleware")
    app.create_flow("Service_C", "Client_A", "Middleware")

    app.create_flow("Service_A", "Middleware", "Server_X")
    app.create_flow("Service_B", "Middleware", "Server_Y")
    app.create_flow("Service_C", "Middleware", "Server_Z")

    app.close()
```

Comment: From the visuals, it seems a good approach. Is there any specific blocker you are facing?

Comment: I don't know the query to do it :-( I'd like to end up with a graph that shows the connections between Client_A and Server_X for the Service_A, and the other connections for Service_B and _C

Comment: So client node should be directly connected to server_x node,  rest of the servers should be connected via the middleware node, is that what is expected?

Comment: Yes, I would like to show that there is a Client - Server connection between Client_A and Server_X because of the Service_A service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have distinct labels for the different types of nodes? i.e., client nodes vs. server nodes

If you would like to retain the graph's current structure, you can use the **Virtual Nodes/Relationships** concept to collapse the intermediary node (i.e., Middleware) and create a (virtual) relationship between the Client and Servers.

Note that the virtual relationship will not exist within the graph or require you to remove the Middleware intermediary, but it will be available at the UI layer for visualization/presentation.

```
MATCH (from:system)-[rel1:service]->(inter:system)-[rel2:service]->(to:system)
RETURN from, to, apoc.create.vRelationship(from,'SERVES', {}, to) as myVirtualRel;
```

Check out https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/.

Answer (score 1):

For the graph, created by this query as depicted in your image:

```
MERGE (c:Client)
MERGE (m:Middleware)
MERGE (s:Server_X)
MERGE (s1:Server_Y)
MERGE (s2:Server_Z)
MERGE (c)-[:SERVICE_A]->(m)-[:SERVICE_A]->(s)
MERGE (c)-[:SERVICE_B]->(m)-[:SERVICE_B]->(s1)
MERGE (c)-[:SERVICE_C]->(m)-[:SERVICE_C]->(s2)
```

This query should work:

```
MATCH (c:Client)-[rel1]->(m:Middleware)-[rel2]->(server) WHERE type(rel1) = type(rel2)
MERGE (c)-[:CONNECTION]->(server)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible just to show the graph without the middleware node but without changing the graph itself? After that I have executed the query (MATCH + MERGE) the graph has additional relations

Comment: The neo4j browser shows the portion of the graph, that we traverse in our query. So the above query will give the complete graph. Try this query, `MATCH (n)-[:CONNECTION]-(m) return n, m`, to get your required graph.

Comment: Last bit, and I won't bother again :-) It worked, but it returned only the nodes. Do you also know if I can show the relationships?

Comment: In other words, I need to show an arrow (even if it does not really exist) between Client_A and Server_X named Service_A. But I don't want to modify the graph

Comment: The graph shown is generated by the data in the database,  if the relationship doesn't exist, then it won't be possible.

Comment: In a large graph, if for example using different queries, I find a relation between two distant nodes (shortest path, if I know a FRIEND of a FRIEND, or if a specific sum of a particular value in a relationship is meet), in these cases how do I show these relations graphically? Do I have to create all these new relationships for each query? Is this the right approach?

Comment: The graph you see is generated on the basis of a query. There are no definite criteria for it. You should focus on how you manage your data, rather than what comes up in visuals